# Find the set where the series converges $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{n^2+1}{3n^2+4}\right)^n(x-2)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

i have to find the set where the series converges:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left (\frac{n^2+1}{3n^2+4}\right)^n(x-2)^n$$
i have found middle at point x=2, and radius=3. with this information I was able to calculate the convergence interval (-1,5). And when i am trying to check series convergent for x=-1 i do not know how to deal with this:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left (\frac{n^2+1}{3n^2+4}\right)^n(-3)^n$$
i will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Hint: does the general term go to zero as $n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: My problem is that i do not know what to do with these parenthesis am i able to multiply them?

Comment: What do you mean, “multiply the parentheses”?

Comment: Am i able to do like that? $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  = (\frac{-3(n^2+1)}{3n^2+4})^n$$

Comment: and if i am able to do like that am i able to do that after? $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]({\frac{-3n^2-3}{3n^2+4)}^n} = -3$$

Comment: Apart from the notation $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}=...$ which you must never, ever use in serious mathematical writing (say, homework) – the notation for the sum of the series is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{...}$ – yes.

Comment: For your second comment: check your syntax and don’t forget your absolute values, but broadly speaking, yes-ish.

Comment: Remember that $a^nb^n=(ab)^n$, whatever the signs.

Comment: I have a problem because when i multiply and use this $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]({\frac{-3n^2-3}{3n^2+4})^n} = 1$$ and if i remember corectly it can not be equal 1 it must be >1 or <1

Comment: because it is cauchy and if it is <1 then series is convergent and when it is >1 series is divergent

Answer (score 2):

The coefficient3 $\approx (1/3)^n$ for large $n$, so $|x-2|\lt 3$ for convergence or $-1\lt x\lt 5$ convergent interval.